# Unit tests urls with pytest

Tags: python, azure-functions, pytest

I have this code:

```
import azure.functions as func
import sys
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
import unittest
import pytest
import azure.functions as func
import os
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
import requests
import json

database_name = os.environ["cosmosDatabase"]
container_name = os.environ["cosmosColl"]
client = CosmosClient.from_connection_string(os.environ["CosmosDBConnStr"])
database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
container = database.get_container_client(container_name)

dummy_data = {
    "Name": "abc",
    "Version": "V1",
    "Maturity Level": "2",
    "Description": "De eisvoorzorgsmaatregelen tabel in onderdeel van de KLIC dataset. Deze tabel geeft een overzicht van de eisvoorzorgsmaatregelen binnen een bepaald vlak (geometrie). De KLIC dataset is voor medewerkers van de gemeente Amsterdam en bedoeld om inzicht te geven in waar welke de kabels en leidingen in de gemeente Amsterdam liggen en van wie ze zijn. Als uitvoerder (in de wet genoemd ‘grondroerder’) ben je wettelijk verplicht vooraf een KLIC-melding te doen, het gebruik van deze dataset vervangt deze plicht niet.",
    "Business goal": "",
    "Theme": "Bouwen",
    "Collection": "Ondergrond",
    "Data Team": "Stedelijke Ontwikkeling en Beheer (SOEB)",
    "Data Product Owner": "Maayke Mars",
    "Data Steward": "",
    "Language": "Nederland",
    "Confidentiality": "Confidential",
    "BIO Quickscan": "Done",
    "Privacy": "Niet persoonlijk identificeerbaar",
    "Privacy Quickscan": "Done",
    "Geo Data": "",
    "History Start": "",
    "Refresh Rate": "",
    "End Date": "",
    "Schema": {
        "Tables": {
            "name": "klicEisvoorzorgsmaatregelen",
            "attributes": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "description": "Unieke id van het object"
                },
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "https://schemas.data.amsterdam.nl/schema@v1.1.1#/definitions/schema"
                },
                "thema": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Thema of discipline waar eisvoorzorgsmaatregel toe behoort"
                },
                "class": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "ID van cluster (niet uniek)"
                },
                "broncode": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Broncode van de beheerder."
                },
                "beheerder": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Naam van geclusturde plannen"
                },
                "evNet": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "De naam van het eisvoorzorgnetwerk"
                },
                "bestand": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "De naam van het meegeleverde PDF bestand die gekoppeld is aan de geometrie"
                },
                "opvraagdatum": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time",
                    "description": "De datum en het tijdstip waarop het Klic orientatieverzoek is uitgevoerd waarmee de gegevens zijn opgevraagd."
                },
                "geometrie": {
                    "$ref": "https://geojson.org/schema/Polygon.json",
                    "description": "Geometrie in RD (epsg:28992)"
                },
                "rgbHexPmkl": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Hex kleurcode volgens PMKL standaard"
                },
                "rgbHexNlcs": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Hex kleurcode volgens NLCS standaard"
                },
                "laagnaam1": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "STATUS-DISCIPLINE"
                },
                "laagnaam2": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "HOOFDGROEP-OBJECT"
                },
                "laagnaam3": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "SUBOBJECT1"
                },
                "laagnaam4": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "ELEMENT"
                },
                "laagnaam5": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Aanvulling van STATUS attribuut"
                },
                "nlcsCodering": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Nederlandse CAD Standaard"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Creation Date": 1686130035,
    "id": "2"
    }
  
container.create_item(body=dummy_data)

def test_get_all_data():
    url = "http://localhost:7071/marketplace"
    resp = requests.get(url)
    resp_body = resp.json()
    if "documents" in resp_body:
        documents = resp_body["_HttpResponse__body"]
        documents_data = json.loads(documents)
        name = documents_data[0].get("Name")
        assert name == "abc"
        assert resp.status_code ==200 

def test_get_existing_themes():
    dummy_data = {
    "Name": "abc",
    "Version": "V1",
    "Maturity Level": "2",
    "Description": "De eisvoorzorgsmaatregelen tabel in onderdeel van de KLIC dataset. Deze tabel geeft een overzicht van de eisvoorzorgsmaatregelen binnen een bepaald vlak (geometrie). De KLIC dataset is voor medewerkers van de gemeente Amsterdam en bedoeld om inzicht te geven in waar welke de kabels en leidingen in de gemeente Amsterdam liggen en van wie ze zijn. Als uitvoerder (in de wet genoemd ‘grondroerder’) ben je wettelijk verplicht vooraf een KLIC-melding te doen, het gebruik van deze dataset vervangt deze plicht niet.",
    "Business goal": "",
    "Theme": "Verkeer",
    "Collection": "Ondergrond",
    "Data Team": "Stedelijke Ontwikkeling en Beheer (SOEB)",
    "Data Product Owner": "Maayke Mars",
    "Data Steward": "",
    "Language": "Nederland",
    "Confidentiality": "Confidential",
    "BIO Quickscan": "Done",
    "Privacy": "Niet persoonlijk identificeerbaar",
    "Privacy Quickscan": "Done",
    "Geo Data": "",
    "History Start": "",
    "Refresh Rate": "",
    "End Date": "",
    "Schema": {
        "Tables": {
            "name": "klicEisvoorzorgsmaatregelen",
            "attributes": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "description": "Unieke id van het object"
                },
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "https://schemas.data.amsterdam.nl/schema@v1.1.1#/definitions/schema"
                },
                "thema": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Thema of discipline waar eisvoorzorgsmaatregel toe behoort"
                },
                "class": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "ID van cluster (niet uniek)"
                },
                "broncode": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Broncode van de beheerder."
                },
                "beheerder": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Naam van geclusturde plannen"
                },
                "evNet": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "De naam van het eisvoorzorgnetwerk"
                },
                "bestand": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "De naam van het meegeleverde PDF bestand die gekoppeld is aan de geometrie"
                },
                "opvraagdatum": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time",
                    "description": "De datum en het tijdstip waarop het Klic orientatieverzoek is uitgevoerd waarmee de gegevens zijn opgevraagd."
                },
                "geometrie": {
                    "$ref": "https://geojson.org/schema/Polygon.json",
                    "description": "Geometrie in RD (epsg:28992)"
                },
                "rgbHexPmkl": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Hex kleurcode volgens PMKL standaard"
                },
                "rgbHexNlcs": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Hex kleurcode volgens NLCS standaard"
                },
                "laagnaam1": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "STATUS-DISCIPLINE"
                },
                "laagnaam2": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "HOOFDGROEP-OBJECT"
                },
                "laagnaam3": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "SUBOBJECT1"
                },
                "laagnaam4": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "ELEMENT"
                },
                "laagnaam5": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Aanvulling van STATUS attribuut"
                },
                "nlcsCodering": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Nederlandse CAD Standaard"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Creation Date": 1686130035,
    "id": "2"
    }
    container.create_item(body=dummy_data)
    url = "http://localhost:7071/marketplace/themes"
    resp = requests.get(url)
    resp_body = resp.json()
    themes = resp_body["_HttpResponse__body"]
    themes_data = json.loads(themes)
    assert "Verkeer" in themes_data
    assert resp.status_code ==200
    container.delete_item(item= "2", partition_key='abc')  # Assuming '2' is the value of the item's 'id' property

def test_get_data_by_id():
    dummy_data = {
    "Name": "abc",
    "Version": "V1",
    "Maturity Level": "2",
    "Description": "De eisvoorzorgsmaatregelen tabel in onderdeel van de KLIC dataset. Deze tabel geeft een overzicht van de eisvoorzorgsmaatregelen binnen een bepaald vlak (geometrie). De KLIC dataset is voor medewerkers van de gemeente Amsterdam en bedoeld om inzicht te geven in waar welke de kabels en leidingen in de gemeente Amsterdam liggen en van wie ze zijn. Als uitvoerder (in de wet genoemd ‘grondroerder’) ben je wettelijk verplicht vooraf een KLIC-melding te doen, het gebruik van deze dataset vervangt deze plicht niet.",
    "Business goal": "",
    "Theme": "Bouwen",
    "Collection": "Ondergrond",
    "Data Team": "Stedelijke Ontwikkeling en Beheer (SOEB)",
    "Data Product Owner": "Maayke Mars",
    "Data Steward": "",
    "Language": "Nederland",
    "Confidentiality": "Confidential",
    "BIO Quickscan": "Done",
    "Privacy": "Niet persoonlijk identificeerbaar",
    "Privacy Quickscan": "Done",
    "Geo Data": "",
    "History Start": "",
    "Refresh Rate": "",
    "End Date": "",
    "Schema": {
        "Tables": {
            "name": "klicEisvoorzorgsmaatregelen",
            "attributes": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "description": "Unieke id van het object"
                },
                "schema": {
                    "$ref": "https://schemas.data.amsterdam.nl/schema@v1.1.1#/definitions/schema"
                },
                "thema": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Thema of discipline waar eisvoorzorgsmaatregel toe behoort"
                },
                "class": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "ID van cluster (niet uniek)"
                },
                "broncode": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Broncode van de beheerder."
                },
                "beheerder": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Naam van geclusturde plannen"
                },
                "evNet": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "De naam van het eisvoorzorgnetwerk"
                },
                "bestand": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "De naam van het meegeleverde PDF bestand die gekoppeld is aan de geometrie"
                },
                "opvraagdatum": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time",
                    "description": "De datum en het tijdstip waarop het Klic orientatieverzoek is uitgevoerd waarmee de gegevens zijn opgevraagd."
                },
                "geometrie": {
                    "$ref": "https://geojson.org/schema/Polygon.json",
                    "description": "Geometrie in RD (epsg:28992)"
                },
                "rgbHexPmkl": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Hex kleurcode volgens PMKL standaard"
                },
                "rgbHexNlcs": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Hex kleurcode volgens NLCS standaard"
                },
                "laagnaam1": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "STATUS-DISCIPLINE"
                },
                "laagnaam2": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "HOOFDGROEP-OBJECT"
                },
                "laagnaam3": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "SUBOBJECT1"
                },
                "laagnaam4": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "ELEMENT"
                },
                "laagnaam5": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Aanvulling van STATUS attribuut"
                },
                "nlcsCodering": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Nederlandse CAD Standaard"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Creation Date": 1686130035,
    "id": "2"
}
    container.create_item(body=dummy_data)
    url = "http://localhost:7071/marketplace/2"
    resp = requests.get(url)
    resp_body = resp.json()
    document = json.loads(resp_body["_HttpResponse__body"])
    name = document["Name"]
    assert name == "abc"
    assert resp.status_code == 200
    container.delete_item(item= "2", partition_key='abc')  # Assuming '2' is the value of the item's 'id' property
    
container.delete_item(item= "2", partition_key='abc')  # Assuming '2' is the value of the item's 'id' property
```

Here, I would like to use my URLs as "/marketplace", "/marketplace/themes", "/marketplace/2" instead of these "http://localhost:7071/marketplace", "http://localhost:7071/marketplace/themes", "http://localhost:7071/marketplace/2". But when I do that I am getting the error: requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/marketplace': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant https:///marketplace?

How can I handle this error?

Comment: I'll give a few sample examples of how to work with URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit tests urls with pytest

will Give sample reference how to unit with URL.

> Used this [Parse URLs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) .

```py
from  urllib.parse  import  urljoin
base_url = "http://localhost:7071"
endpoints = ["/marketplace",  "/marketplace/themes",  "/marketplace/2"]
for  endpoint  in  endpoints:
full_url = urljoin(base_url,  endpoint)
print(f"GET request to: {full_url}")
print("Hello, World!")
print()
```

Unit test case:

```py
from  urllib.parse  import  urljoin
import  pytest
def  generate_url(base_url,  endpoint):

return  urljoin(base_url,  endpoint)
def  test_urls():
base_url = "http://localhost:7071"
endpoints = [
("/marketplace",  "http://localhost:7071/marketplace"),

("/marketplace/themes",  "http://localhost:7071/marketplace/themes"),

("/marketplace/2",  "http://localhost:7071/marketplace/2")

]
for  endpoint,  expected_url  in  endpoints:
generated_url = generate_url(base_url,  endpoint)
assert  generated_url == expected_url
```

**Output:**

[image]